# Dive into Python 3 - convert to ePUB

Tags: linux, python, ebook, epub

The ebook Dive into Python 3 is available on GitHub. [This script](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintopython3/blob/master/publish) creates the HTML and PDF versions.

Is it possible to generate an ePUB version from this on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is. You should try `Calibre` (sudo apt-get install calibre, [see this Web page](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux). It should be enough for just about `any` conversion. If for any reason you do not like it, try [this Web page](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/EPub#Conversion_software) for alternatives.

Comment: Forgot to tell: not to convert pdf to epub (will work crappy), would rather base on the html version. Will it work in this case too?

Comment: Calibre can do just about anything. Should you be unhappy with the outcome, the second link I posted has alternatives.